# struts2 global result not redirecting to action

Tags: struts2, global, interceptor

I have a custom interceptor (TransferInterceptor) that checks for a function change within my application.  When it changes, the interceptor returns a post-processing string (the result) containing the global results name of the action that I want to redirect to.  I have the results defined in the global results of my struts.xml file, but they do not redirect to the specified action.  I have a 'Login' global result that works fine, but it is being called from a JSP with:

```
<s:a action="Login.action">Login</s:a>
```

The struts.xml file:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="AuthenticationInterceptor" class="com.purchasing.utils.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
        <interceptor name="TransferInterceptor" class="com.purchasing.utils.TransferInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="TransferInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="AuthenticationInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="secureStack" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="Login">login.jsp</result>
        <result name="RESULTA" type="redirect">ACTIONA</result>
        <result name="RESULTB" type="redirect">ACTIONB</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="Login" class="com.purchasing.actions.Login">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="ACTIONA" class="com.purchasing.actions.ACTIONA">
        <result name="success">ACTIONA.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">ACTIONA.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">ACTIONA.jsp</result>
    </action>   

    <action name="ACTIONB" class="com.purchasing.actions.ACTIONB">
        <result name="success">ACTIONB.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">ACTIONB.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">ACTIONB.jsp</result>
    </action>                

</package>
```

The TransferInterceptor:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception
{
    String result = ai.invoke();

    session = ai.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    fl = (FunctionLine) session.get(Constants.FUNCTION_LINE);
    function = fl.getFl_function();
    last_function = (Integer) session.get(Constants.LAST_FUNCTION);

    if (function != last_function) {
       session.put(Constants.LAST_FUNCTION, new Integer(function));
       switch (function) {
              case 61: return "RESULTA";
              case 62: return "RESULTB";
       }
       return "error";
    }
    else {
       return result;
    }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to redirect to an action use `redirectAction` result type instead of `redirect` which is used to redirect to static resources

Comment: That is the answer @LukaszLenart, you should publish it :)

Comment: I changed the type="redirect" to type="redirectAction" and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure your interceptor is being called?

Comment: Yes.  I see where the "RESULTB" string is being returned, but then the ACTIONB is not executed.

Comment: it won't executed, since it has to go through the same interceptor stack which returned "RESULTB" before the ACTIONB can be fired and hence, it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Try to turn off some interceptors which might prevent the action execution.

Answer (score 2):

As per @Lukasz comment :

`If you want to redirect to an action use redirectAction result type instead of redirect which is used to redirect to static resources`

It still won't work, because the ACTIONB & ACTIONA never executes since they go through the same interceptor stack, which returned redirectAction result & hence, it's kinda stuck in an infinite loop.